# Color some x-labels in altair plot?

Tags: python, altair

How can I change the color of only some x or y-labels?

For example, in the example below, I would like the y-ticks 4,5,6 and 7 to have red color, while the rest remain black.
[image: example]

Comment: I tried looking for it, but couldn't find a way to change the color partially. If you want to change all of them, you can do it with the following. `alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(x='x', y='y').configure_axisY(labelColor='red')`

Comment: @r-beginners check my code but it is not using `altair` module and let me know what is the problem in it, some user downvote it.

Comment: @Exploore X The questioner's intention is to use altair to solve a problem.

Comment: But you also mention in your comment that it not possible with this module

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `alt.condition` to get a conditional axis label color:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'y': [5, 3, 6, 7, 2],
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='x',
    y=alt.Y('y', axis=alt.Axis(
        labelColor=alt.condition('datum.value > 3 && datum.value < 7', alt.value('red'), alt.value('black'))
    ))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Is this how you do the if condition? It was a good lesson for me.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: How to add condition to the x axis : 
example condition from a list(dynamically generated ) : [A,D,E]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how come this works, but if you replace the condition with a selection, it starts complaining that the values are defined as `alt.value` instead of just strings.

Answer (score 0):

Change color of one tick one-by-one using `plt.gca().get_yticklabels()` object, and by using `set_color` attribute of this object change default color with conditon

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'y':[5, 3, 6, 7, 2]
    }
)

plt.bar(df['x'], df['y'])

my_colors = 'red'

for ticklabel, y in zip(plt.gca().get_yticklabels(), range(max(df['y']))):
    if y in [4, 5, 2, 1]:
        ticklabel.set_color(my_colors)

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great to have for matplotlib! But I'm using this library: https://altair-viz.github.io/index.html